# Pandas binning of integer for years

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, binning

Given this sample data:

```
 year   zan_inj bins
0   1980    15  NaN
1   1981    18  (1980.0, 1985.0]
2   1982    23  (1980.0, 1985.0]
3   1983    33  (1980.0, 1985.0]
4   1984    42  (1980.0, 1985.0]
5   1985    54  (1980.0, 1985.0]
6   1986    59  (1985.0, 1990.0]
7   1987    65  (1985.0, 1990.0]
8   1988    76  (1985.0, 1990.0]
9   1989    86  (1985.0, 1990.0]
```

Two issues.  I want to group all the bin values to get the dataframe below and also want the bin that starts with 1980 to actually include the top line values that would be in the year 1980.  My two columns are both 'int" types.

Ideal output:

```
total   bin
185    (1980.0, 1985.0]
311    (1985.0, 1990.0]
```

I have tried:

```
df.groupby('bins').size()
pd.cut(df['year'], bins=bins).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `include_lowest`, but this will make the lower boundary not int

```
pd.cut(df['year'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True).value_counts()
```

Update

```
out = df.groupby( pd.cut(df['year'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True)).agg({'total':'sum'})
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but trying the above code actually results in a count of how many times the actual bin value appears in a row.  Like this.  (1979.999, 1985.0]    6
(2010.0, 2015.0]      5
(2005.0, 2010.0]      5
(2000.0, 2005.0]      5
(1995.0, 2000.0]      5
(1990.0, 1995.0]      5
(1985.0, 1990.0]      5
(2015.0, 2020.0]      4